# Are these files really Malware?

Tags: linux, malware

When running LMD (maldet), it found the following as malware -->

```
{YARA}r57shell_php_php : /usr/local/chkrootkit/chkrootkit

{YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/sbembenek/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sync Data/LevelDB/000742.log
```

It's hard to believe chkrootkit is malware, but why is it coming up on the list?

And I'm unclear about the chrome log file being on there as well.

thanks!

Comment: Anti-Malware software contains signatures that help them identify common malware in files on your machine.   Because of this [other anti-malware programs](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/8b/7d/0e8b7d2c53195177a326670609fcb7ea.jpg) will match those signatures and be marked as malware.

Comment: Thanks for the help!